# constructing a sum of squares modulo an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This question refers to the proof of Theorem 7.3, p. 98 of the pdf http://math.berkeley.edu/~bernd/cbms.pdf.
The statement of the theorem and its proof do not depend on what precedes them.

Let $I$ be an ideal of $S=\mathbb{R}[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. Let $U=\left\{u,\bar{u}\right\}$ be a pair of complex points of $V(I)$. Let $g(x) \in S$ be a non-negative polynomial.

The proof states that we can construct an element $S_U(x)$ of $S$ that is a sum of squares and that is congruent to $g(x)$ modulo $\langle x-u\rangle\cap \langle x-\bar{u}\rangle$, where $\langle x-u\rangle=\langle x_1-u_1,\cdots,x_n-u_n\rangle$. How can we construct such a $S_U(x)$?